# Bootstrap slider advancing on image click not working after adding ImgLiquid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently added ImgLiquid to resize images inside the Bootstrap carousel, which worked perfectly. However, now my slider no longer works. I had the slider programmed to advance on image click. The indicators do not work either and I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
// ImgLiquid
$('.imgLiquidFill').imgLiquid({
  fill: false,
  verticalAlign: 'left'
});

// Slider advances on image click
var i = 0;
$('#slider img').click(function() {
  $('#slider').carousel(++i);
});
```

```html
<!-- Carousel -->
<section id="slider" class="carousel slide slide-container">

  <!-- Images -->
  <div class="carousel-inner imgLiquidFill imgLiquid" role="listbox">

    <?php foreach( $images as $image ) : ?>
    <div class="item <?php if($count1==0) : echo 'active'; endif; ?>">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <?php $count1++; endforeach; ?>

  </div>
  <!-- end .carousel-inner -->
```

Comment: Figured it out. Just changed the click target to the container instead of the image.

$('#slider .carousel-inner').click(function()